# laravel query builder sql group by taking the max of a different column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a table with the relevant portion of the schema being:

```
id (autoincrement)
status (varchar)
tracking_id (varchar)
```

The table is insert only, so on attempts they are inserted with a status of attempted, and when they complete, a status of sent. They can also be set to a status of cancelled at a later time, which would create a third record. The common field to pair them together is this tracking_id field.

My goal for the query is to get one record back for each tracking_id, getting created if it exists, otherwise sent, otherwise attempted.

I'm using laravel query builder so right now the sql looks like:

```
DB::connection($connection)
    ->table('table')
    ->groupBy('tracking_id')
    ->get();
```

I'm getting back the attempted record for result sets that have other statuses. I'm not sure how to make it return the record for other statuses.

I'm also not opposed to writing out a query to do this, but laravel automatically handles the group by so I don't have to group all the fields (of which there are a significant number of them).

Comment: why don't you order by insert time and always get the last result inserted?

Comment: @HanlinWang I need to get back more than a single record, I'm getting one per tracking_id. I can't just add an order by because that has no bearing on the group by when I group by tracking_id.

Comment: maybe you can try add ->max('status') into query